# Query hangs only when in script

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an update statement that takes about 14s to run against a ~1 million record table. However, if that query is in a script, which includes around 10 other creates, inserts, updates, etc., then that same update will just hang and never finish. I've tried running the script in DataGrip and from the command line with no luck.

I can run all of the statements up until the problem one together and then run that update separately and it's fine. I just can't run it with the others. Has anyone else ever experienced anything like this?

Comment: Does the script start a transaction?

Comment: It does not. It's just a bunch of statements one after another. It creates a couple of tables, inserts some data into those, and then does some calculations and updates, etc.

Comment: Does one of the definitions (create, alter) touch the table wich get's updated?

Comment: The create happens first and there are no alters. Data is then inserted into that table from several other tables. There are some temp tables that get created as well, but for the most part just a lot of updates to that table that was freshly created. I'm not sure if I am allowed to post the code, but I can check, if that would help.

Comment: Very odd. Don't even know if the code would help. Maybe packing the working statements in a transaction and calling the problematic update afterwards would help. But that's just a guess.
Some MySQL Guru knowing how to monitor and interpret query optimizer and execution plans is needed here.